# Converting a suffix based date in R

Tags: r

I'd like to convert the following date format: Wed 1st Jan 2014 to 01/01/2014

The suffix following the 1 is giving me the most trouble and preventing me from using the standard methods.

Comment: Hi there, by _suffix_, are you referring to the ordinal? i.e. "st" in "1st"?

Comment: Yes that's what I meant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be `dmy` from `lubridate` to convert to `Date` class and then `format` it to required format

```
library(lubridate)
format(dmy(str1), "%d/%m/%Y")
#[1] "01/01/2014"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "Wed 1st Jan 2014"
```